# How to store key-value data for cocoa apps within the app itself?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, dictionary, nsbundle, key-value-store

I have an info dictionary that contains user data. Currently, it is written to an xml file in the same directory as the app. However, I'm pretty certain cocoa allows me to write this xml file into the application bundle or some Resources directory within the app.

Can someone teach me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use `NSFileManager` to `createFileAtPath:contents:attributes:` in the `NSDocumentDirectory` (relative to your bundle this is `/Documents`) with the `NSData` of your xml file.
Something like this:

```
NSString *myFileName = @"SOMEFILE.xml";
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

// This will give the absolute path of the Documents directory for your App
NSString *docsDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

// This will join the Documents directory path and the file name to make a single absolute path (exactly like os.path.join, if you python)
NSString *xmlWritePath = [docsDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:myFileName];

// Replace this next line with something to turn your XML into an NSData
NSData *xmlData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:@"http://someurl.com/mydoc.xml"];

// Write the file at xmlWritePath and put xmlData in the file.
BOOL created = [fileManager createFileAtPath:xmlWritePath contents:xmlData attributes:nil];
if (created) {
    NSLog(@"File created successfully!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"File creation FAILED!");
}

// Only necessary if you are NOT using ARC and you alloc'd the NSData above:
[xmlData release], xmlData = nil;
```

Some references:

[`NSFileManager` Reference Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
[`NSData` Reference Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

---

**Edit**

In response to your comments, this would be typical usage of `NSUserDefaults` to save serializable data between App runs:

```
// Some data that you would want to replace with your own XML / Dict / Array / etc
NSMutableDictionary *nodeDict1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"object1", @"key1", nil];
NSMutableDictionary *nodeDict2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"object2", @"key2", nil];
NSArray *nodes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nodeDict1, nodeDict2, nil];

// Save the object in standardUserDefaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nodes forKey:@"XMLNODELIST"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To retrieve a saved value (next time the App is launched, or from another part of the App, etc):

```
NSArray *xmlNodeList = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"XMLNODELIST"];
```

[`NSUserDefaults` Reference Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: NSDocumentDirectory is saved in iCloud. Be careful to not put big files into, Apple will warn you...

Comment: Is there any way to not store my xml file outside my app? Can I store it inside my app inside the resources bundle or something?

Comment: @dragoncharmer Sure, that is what `NSUserDefaults` is for.  I'll toss up an example.

Comment: @dragoncharmer Np, happy to help ).

Comment: @dragoncharmer: You can put a file inside your app at build time, but you can't rely on your app bundle being writable on the user's machine. What you want is probably the Application Support folder.

Comment: A non-trivial number of users will get angry at you if you put random files in their Documents folder. For files created by the application and not the user, you should put them in the Application Support folder.

Comment: @PeterHosey I just realized that this question could possibly be about osx App's and not iOS App's.... @@dragoncharmer - if this is not for an iOS App, then Peter's suggestions are probably correct as I assumed from the start that this was for iOS.  Sry bout that.